# How to import CSV file in Excel using VBA with explicit column-format specifications

Tags: excel, vba, csv

How to import CSV files in Excel using VBA/Macro where the format of each column is explicit defined in the code?

Comment: Getting Excel to interpret the datatypes correctly is always a headache. But you could just use the Text File Driver of the ACE OLEDB engine. So create a `schema.ini` file with the column settings and then do a `SELECT *` from the file. See the initial code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58867643/1745616

Comment: But it will  add several additional dependencies, the OLEDB engine I assume has to be referenced and an extra .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the variables in line 8 and 11-15, that's all:
`TotalColumns`: Total number of columns. First column = 1 (not 0)
`TextColumns`, `NumberColumns`, `DateColumns`, `SkipColumns` & `HideColumns` : Specify which columns belong to which format-group

```
Sub ImportCSV_xxx()
    
    Dim CSV_File As String, TotalColumns As Integer
    Dim TextColumns As Variant, NumberColumns As Variant, DateColumns As Variant, SkipColumns As Variant, HideColumns As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, ColumnFormat As Variant
              
    'SET NUMBER OF COLUMNS (zero based index)
    TotalColumns = 10 '1 based index
    
    'SPECIFY COLUMN-FORMATS (1 based index)
    TextColumns = Array(1, 2)
    NumberColumns = Array(4,5)
    DateColumns = Array(6, 7)
    SkipColumns = Array(8)
    HideColumns = Array(1, 4)
        
    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ReDim ColumnFormat(TotalColumns - 1)
        
    'TEXT columns
    For Each i In TextColumns
        ColumnFormat(i - 1) = xlTextFormat
    Next
    
    'DATE columns (Y-M-D)
    For Each i In DateColumns
        ColumnFormat(i - 1) = xlYMDFormat 'xlMDYFormat, xlDMYFormat, xlYMDFormat, xlMYDFormat, xlDYMFormat, xlYDMFormat, xlEMDFormat
    Next
    
    'NUMBER columns:
    For Each i In NumberColumns
        ColumnFormat(i - 1) = xlGeneralFormat
        WS.Columns(i).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Next
    
    'SKIP columns:
    For Each i In SkipColumns
        ColumnFormat(i - 1) = xlSkipColumn
    Next
    
    'HIDE columns:
    For Each i In HideColumns
        WS.Columns(i).Hidden = True
    Next
    
    'ASK FOR CSV FILE:
    CSV_File = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Provide Text or CSV File:")
    
    'IMPORT FILE:
    With WS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & CSV_File, Destination:=WS.Range("A1")) 'ActiveCell
        '*** GENERAL SETTINGS ***
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        '.TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(5, 4)
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        
        '*** SET DATA-FORMAT OF EACH COLUMN ***
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = ColumnFormat
        '.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat, xlSkipColumn, xlGeneralFormat)
       
        '*** DELIMITER CONFIGURATION ***
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        '.TextFileOtherDelimiter = "SomeString"
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False 'Multiple delimiters are treated as a single delimiter
        
        '*** GENERAL NUMBER CONFIGURATIONS ***
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = "."
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = False

        '*** REFRESH DATA ***
        .Refresh
        '.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'this is neccesary if a second import can be done
    End With
End Sub
```